# X11 forwarding fails when switching users

Tags: ssh, x11

X11 forwarding works when I am logged in my CentOS 6.6 cluster as myself (using `ssh -AY user@ipaddress`).  When I try switching users, e.g. `sudo su user2` and try to fire up `xterm`, I get the error :

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>
> xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:11.0

How do I get X11 forwarding to work in this case?

Comment: basically, you don't, unless you will find some hack to do that. Your `user2` does not have permissions to write to `user` socket, which is correct. You might change permissions on such sockets, but then you might open security hole to your workstation.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/131101/xforwarding-doesnt-allow-for-switching-users

Answer (score 1):

using `sudo su` is likely to loose all authorization.

setup ssh key authentication, then use `ssh -AY user2@localhost` (or  `ssh -AY user2@localhost xterm` )

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first to suffer this issue.  The cause is quite simple: your X server is (quite reasonably) set to require an authentication token, and the second user doesn't have access to that token.  There are a number of solutions:

1. Don't run X11 applications as the other user.  As yourself, start an xterm running a shell as the other user:

   ```
   xterm -e sudo -s user2
   ```

   Obviously this approach will not work if you really need to run a GUI application as the other user, but it's always worth considering before anything more complex.
2. Allow user2 to access your X server without authentication.  As yourself, add this user using xhost:

   ```
   xhost +SI:localuser:user2
   ```
3. Install `sux` and use that instead of `su`.  It's a simple shell wrapper, and it's now mostly fallen by the wayside, given solutions such as the next one.
4. Configure `su` and `sudo` to use `pam_xauth`.  This is a standard module (in `libpam-modules` on Debian).  All that is required is to add the line

   ```
   session  optional  pam_xauth.so
   ```

   to `/etc/pam.d/su` and to `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.  There are additional options (see the man page) but you're unlikely to need them.