# X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication

Tags: x11, sudo, pam, su, xauth

First of all what I want to do:

I want to login to a server via `ssh`. Then change change the user via `sudo su user` and start some application on my screen.

Some collegues do it by

```
su user
export DISPLAY=<IP>:0
```

an it works.

---

I connect to a server via `ssh -X user@server`. Then I start a X11 application. This works fine (although there are warnings).

Warnings:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: failed to query the version
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 1 (BadRequest), sequence: 414, resource id: 1897, major code: 155 (Unknown), minor code: 1
```

---

If I run `sudo su` (or `sudo su user`) and start the program or run it via `sudo myprogram` there is an error.

Error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:11.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

---

I found some articles about this problem.

[X11 forwarding fails when switching users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272829/x11-forwarding-fails-when-switching-users)

[ssh connection. X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412065/ssh-connection-x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication)

---

So extend the `/etc/pam.d/su` file and the `/etc/pam/sudo` file by

```
session  optional  pam_xauth.so
```

And later I changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by adding:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

and restarting the sshd by `systemctl restart ssh.service`. `ssh -T` says `x11forwarding yes`

But nothing changed.

Does anybody know what to do? Its important to check some changes on the users program configurations after making changes.

Comment: Any reason why instead of using `su user2`, you cannot do a second `ssh -X user2@server` in a different terminal window?

Comment: @dirkt Because I would need the password of "user2" then.

Comment: Use ssh keys instead of the password? Or maybe even a group key for testing? The problem really is that the forwarding socket and auth information can be specific to the user. You can start looking at Xauthority permissions and permissions on the socket, but letting ssh set up everything for you is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 19):

Since many people will come here with the same error message, not realising it's unrelated to the use of `su`, I'd like to point out that similar symptoms now occur for a very different reason:

Anything installed with Snap wont work. So `xeyes` and `xclock` might work, but a new install of `chromium-browser` or `firefox` on Ubuntu wont.

The workaround is to simply do: `export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority` before running the remote X11 application.

- Ref 1: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-forwarding-using-ssh/2381
- Ref 2: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/16528/3

Comment: Funny, this turned out to also be my solution, firefox did not work via x11 forwarding (ubuntu 22.04 on multipass vm), however I did not use snap to install firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure how, but this fixed my problem with `sudouser@remoteserver>sudo virt-manager` from a local ubuntu 2204 desktop. Now I can move on with my life.

Comment: This was the right solution for me as well. Annoying that it is a problem in the first place :/

Answer (score 2):

**Insecure** option:

On the host from which you log in, execute

```
xhost +
```

or, only a little more secure

```
xhost <IP you want to log in to>
```

This will allow connections from the remote host.

Why is this insecure?  Any program and user from that host (or any program/user from any host, with `xhost +`) will be able to access your screen and read all key presses on the machine you execute `xhost` on.

**More secure** option:

Add the authorisation key for your X11 server to the remote machine:

On the local machine, list the necessary "magic cookie":

```
# xauth list
hostname/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

On the remote machine, add the secret to your `~/.Xauthority` file, easiest again with `xauth`:

```
# setenv DISPLAY <ORIGIN_IP>:0
# xauth add <ORIGIN_IP>:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

Please note that X11 protocol data between these machines is still unencrypted and therefore prone to attacks.

Comment: Ah, there is 'my_computer' -->ssh--> 'me@remote_computer' -->sudo su--> 'root@remote_computer'. Where I have to set `xhost +` and how to get off again (`xhost -`?).

Comment: `xhost +` on the machine with X11, where you sit. Yes, undo by `xhost -`. Better use the second option. though. Keys are per-user so use `xhost add ...` as the one that starts the X11 program to be  displayed.

Comment: `xhost +` doesn't work. But I'm a fool. I forgot `export DISPLAY=<myIP>:0`. Then I get another error... (Qt libraries - but I think I'ts another theme).

Comment: After `export DISPLAY <ORIGIN_IP>:0` and `xauth add <ORIGIN_IP> MIT...` there is an `bad display name "123.123.123.123" in "add" command`. If I add ":0" at the end of the IP it is executed. `xauth list` gives then `my_computer:0  MIT...`. But connection is still refused.

Comment: Sorry, added the missing ":0". You could try `xauth add my_computer/unix:0 01234...` but it works without it for me. Please check the shell syntax, btw, by testing `echo $DISPLAY`. Perhaps the syntax is `export DISPLAY=<origin_ip>:0` so with equals sign. You can also try `xauth add $DISPLAY 0123...` (always replacing 0123... with your secret of course).

Comment: looks like the OP is forwarding X via ssh. does your following comment still apply? "X11 protocol data between these machines is still unencrypted "

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Yes, perhaps. The question talks about how colleagues do it: Logging in via `ssh` but not forwarding X requests over it. The way OP tries it, likely not relevant. The problem seems to stem from a different issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user1 is the original user (whose password you know) and user2 is the target user (unknown password), I can get this to work:

```
% ssh -Y user1@target-box
Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

user1@target-box% sudo -u user2 bash
Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

user2@target-box% cp  ~user1/.Xauthority  ~user2

user2@target-box% xterm &
```

Note that this also assumes the correct sshd config you spelled out in your post.