# Cannot forward firefox or chrome via X11

Tags: x11

I've got a headless Debian host and a Virtualbox client. Previously I was able to forward Firefox from Debian to the local box, but suddenly it just stopped working.

xterm or xeyes still work as before, no issues.

I'm trying to launch Firefox:

```
ssh -v  -X <hostname> firefox
```

And the result is as follows:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 2

debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384

debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 33734

debug1: channel 1: new [x11]

debug1: confirm x11

debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384

debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 33742

debug1: channel 2: new [x11]

debug1: confirm x11

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 3

debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 2

debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384

debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 33754

debug1: channel 1: new [x11]

debug1: confirm x11

Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0

debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0

debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0

debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 2

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 1

Transferred: sent 102100, received 18628 bytes, in 31.7 seconds

Bytes per second: sent 3224.1, received 588.2

debug1: Exit status 1
```

Chromium gives the following output:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

[69559:69559:0920/114752.211400:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY

[69559:69559:0920/114752.211590:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into this too. xeyes/xterm works but chromium-browser and firefox don't. Did you solve it?

Comment: Oh, just stumbled on answer/workaround here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709787/94561. Stuff installed with snap doesn't work.

Comment: Same here, tried xyes and it works but fails with Firefox. @dgrogan, thanks a lot for the pointer. I am extremely annoyed that it's 2023 and I can't X-forward firefox to Ubuntu 22.04. First issues with the X-forwarding (I needed to edit the /etc/sshd/sshd_config on the server, an extravagant setting called "AddressFamily inet"), now this. What a big crap sometimes Linux world is ...